# What is correct settings for sending email through godaddy SMTP?

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

I am using GoDaddy Professional Email (NOT Workspace Email) under Email & Office. For my website, I want to email users using PHPMailer. I have used all the credentials according to GoDaddy Email Server infos.

According to GoDaddy, the outgoing server settings are:

- SMTP Host : 'smtpout.secureserver.net'
- Port: 465
- Security : 'ssl'

I have set my PHPMailer code as follows:

```
<?php

try
{
    $email = new PHPMailer(TRUE);
    $email->isSMTP();
    $email->SMTPDebug = 2;
    $email->SMTPAuth = TRUE;
    $email->SMTPAutoTLS = FALSE;
    $email->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
    $email->Host = "smtpout.secureserver.net";
    $email->Port = 465;
    $email->Username = "myUserName";
    $email->Password = "MyPassword";

    $email->setFrom("address@from.com", "Name");
    $email->addAddress("address@to.com", "Name");
    $email->isHTML(TRUE);
    $email->Body = "My HTML Code";
    $email->Subject = "My Subject";
    $email->send();
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    // $email->ErrorInfo;
}

?>
```

The above code throwing following error:

`2019-08-14 10:55:58 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111)
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting`

I have searched for solutions. Some Stackoverflow questions discuss about GoDaddy Workspace Email. But I am frustrated to find a solution till now. Please help me if I am doing anything wrong.

Comment: `Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111)` means "there's no server listening at the server and port provided." Either the port or the host is wrong, or the service is down. That's probably for your provider's tech support to investigate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have found the following setting working. **This may be useful.**

**Use 80 as port**

```
<?php

try
{
    $email = new PHPMailer(TRUE);
    $email->isSMTP();
    $email->SMTPDebug = 2;
    $email->SMTPAuth = TRUE;
    $email->SMTPAutoTLS = FALSE;
    $email->SMTPSecure = "tls";
    $email->Host = "smtpout.secureserver.net";
    $email->Port = 80;
    $email->Username = "GoDaddy Professional Email Username";
    $email->Password = "GoDaddy Professional Email Password";

    $email->setFrom("address@from.com", "Name");
    $email->addAddress("address@to.com", "Name");
    $email->isHTML(TRUE);
    $email->Body = "My HTML Code";
    $email->Subject = "My Subject";
    $email->send();
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    // $email->ErrorInfo;
}

?>`
```

Comment: To my surprise, this is actually [true](http://smtpimap.email/godaddy.com-smtp-imap-email-settings.html)! What's more you can indeed telnet to port 80 and get an SMTP response, and it does offer STARTTLS encryption. This also gives something of a hint as to how awful GoDaddy is...

Comment: fyi ... smtpout.secureserver.net was insightful. I had to add "smtpout.secureserver.net" to my domain's DNS records and that finally got my email working. Side note, I have it working on port 25 just fine -- i didn't test port 80. Anyway, thank you for sharing. In case someone needs this, the DNS record i added was: CNAME smtp smtpout.secureserver.net N/A 1 Hour

Answer (score 2):

My answer is to say that: Hiranmoy's suggestion on Aug 14 at 14:56 should be the approved answer. The amount of headaches Godaddy causes with this simple piece of functionality deserves a tested, working solution and Hiranmoy's is the only one I have found after many hours of searching. Here is Hiranmoy's snippet with missing includes added:

```
    <?php
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

    require 'Exception.php';
    require 'PHPMailer.php';
    require 'SMTP.php';

    try
    {
        $email = new PHPMailer(TRUE);
        $email->isSMTP();
        $email->SMTPDebug = 2;
        $email->SMTPAuth = TRUE;
        $email->SMTPAutoTLS = FALSE;
        $email->SMTPSecure = "tls";
        $email->Host = "smtpout.secureserver.net";
        $email->Port = 80;
        $email->Username = "GoDaddy Professional Email Username";
        $email->Password = "GoDaddy Professional Email Password";

        $email->setFrom("address@from.com", "Name");
        $email->addAddress("address@to.com", "Name");
        $email->isHTML(TRUE);
        $email->Body = "My HTML Code";
        $email->Subject = "My Subject";
        $email->send();
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        // $email->ErrorInfo;
    }
    ?>
```