# couldn't send email with godaddy hosting

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, zoho

I used godaddy hosting for my website. I tried to send the contact form fill to my personal gmail and it worked (send as a spam). If I change it to my website email, it said successfully send but there's none in the inbox. (the code below is suggested by godaddy)

I used zoho mail for my website email and I also tried using their configuration (their host and tsl security), but it didn't work. There's always "https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/troubleshooting" popup when I tried to send the contact form filling

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
    //If you don't receive the email, enable and configure these parameters below: 
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->Mailer='smtp';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = false;
    $mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false; 
    //$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 25;                                    // TCP port to connect to  587 or 465
    $mail->Host = 'localhost';                  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers, example: smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com
    $mail->Username = 'support@domain.com';                    // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'xxxx';                    // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPOptions = array('ssl' => array('verify_peer' => false,'verify_peer_name' => false,'allow_self_signed' => true));
    
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->From = $email;
    $mail->FromName = $name;
    if(strpos($to, ',') !== false){
        $email_addresses = explode(',', $to);
        foreach($email_addresses as $email_address) {
            $mail->AddAddress(trim($email_address));
        }
    }
    else {$mail->AddAddress($to);}
    $mail->AddReplyTo($email, $name);
    $mail->Subject = $subject; 
    $mail->isHTML(true);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is correct settings for sending email through godaddy SMTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57493941/what-is-correct-settings-for-sending-email-through-godaddy-smtp)

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work. "connection time out" @RoAchterberg

Comment: Please demonstrate how you've tried 'it' by showing us your updated code.

Comment: $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->Mailer='smtp';
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false; 
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            
        $mail->Port = 80;         $mail->Host = 'smtpout.secureserver.net';                 
        $mail->Username = 'support@domain.com';                 
        $mail->Password = 'xxxxxx';

Comment: Try `telnet`'ing to `smtpout.secureserver.net` (`telnet smtpout.secureserver.net 80`). If that doesn't work, then check your outgoing firewall rules.

Comment: I write it before the php closing, but it sais "syntax error, unexpected t_string". When I send the contact from, it said unrifined

Comment: Please show us, don't tell us. Please provide the *full code* you have been testing with most recently.

Comment: the recent code is the bellow post

Comment: It's unlikely to be possible to send email through GoDaddy with out it being considered forgery, unless it's from an actual godaddy.com email address, and as a result messages will either not be delivered, or will be considered spam. The single best thing to do is not use GoDaddy.

Comment: So, should I change the hosting? @Synchro

Comment: Probably. GoDaddy is cheap in every sense, but many hosting providers (e.g. AWS, Scaleway) have SMTP restrictions of one kind or another, so if you do choose to move, check how they handle email first.

Comment: Do you have any recommendation? If you don't mind to share it, what hosting providers do you use currently (the one with no strict regulation such as SMTP restrictions)?

Comment: You can try SparkPost - they allow connections on port 2525 so this will probably go through the GoDaddy firewall. Google cloud also blocks port 25 - at least outgoing connections but most probably also the incoming ones.