# PHP mail Sending working fine with php alone but if i integrate in laravel not working the same code in Godaddy Shared Hosting

Tags: php, laravel, phpmailer

SMTP PHPMailer Error in the application.

This is the PHP code working and sending the mail perfectly very quickly. But if you integrate this code into the Laravel application. I am getting errors.

> SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110)
> SMTP connect() failed.

As a php file with this code is sending mail in GoDaddy Shared hosting. But if integrate this code in Laravel, its returning error as under

SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110)
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting.

What would be issue here , Please any experts help would be greatly appreciated.
Code tested as under

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php';
$email='xyz@gmail.com';//change email to receipents email
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0; 
$mail->SMTPAuth = false;//SMTP authentication should be false
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'none';// Security type should be none 
$mail->Host = 'localhost';// SMTP host name should be localhost
$mail->Port = 25;  
$mail->setFrom('support@xyz.com', 'test email');     
$mail->addReplyTo('support@xyz.in', 'test email');  
$mail->addAddress($email);  // Add a recipient
$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                
$mail->isHTML(true);                                 
$mail->Subject = 'Test email';
$mail->Body    = "Test Body";;
$mail->send();
?>
```

Comment: Are you hosting both code on same hosting/server & php versions?

Comment: Yes same hosting ..same domain . but in different directory

Comment: You're using port 25 and when I click the link in your question it says: _"Popular US hosting provider GoDaddy imposes very strict (to the point of becoming almost useless) constraints on sending an email. They block outbound SMTP to ports 25, 465 and 587 to all servers except their own. This problem is the subject of many frustrating questions on Stack Overflow. If you find your script works on your local machine, but not when you upload it to GoDaddy, this will be what's happening to you."_. In what way is your situation different from the explanation you've already found?

Comment: Maybe [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57493941/what-is-correct-settings-for-sending-email-through-godaddy-smtp) can help, but you should look in the support documents of your shared hosting to see what is possible for you, or ask GoDaddy. Most people here don't use GoDaddy and therefore cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: Hi this above mentioning code is shooting mails . when i integrate that piece of code to laravel project its not working ..

Comment: Please don't just say: _"its not working"_. There's no real information in that other than that it doesn't do what you want it to. Do you get an error? It's also completely unclear, from your comment, to which code _"this above mentioning code"_ is referring. Is it the code in your question, or one of the 3 pieces of code you can find in the link of my comment?

Comment: What do you mean by "integrate into Laravel" _specifically_? How did you achieve the integration,  precisely? And why do you think that's making any difference to whether it can make a connection or not? That bit of the code hasn't changed. Which makes me wonder whether what's really happening is that some other mail code is being executed in the case where it fails, and not this code at all. Have you done any proper debugging to verify what exactly is happening? Did you turn on phpmailer debugging, as per that Troubleshooting guide? I don't think you've shown us a [mre] of the problem

Comment: As the others have said, there’s not enough information here. In spite of being PHPMailer’s maintainer, I would recommend that you use Laravel’s built-in mail classes if you’re using Laravel. You’re using a very old  and unsupported version of PHPMailer, though that’s not the problem here. SMTPDebug won’t help much here because you’re not using SMTP.